# Python Inheritance, Move method to a common class

Tags: python, django, oop, model

I am forgetting OOP terminology which was related to inheritance and which used classes dynamically. Here is what I am looking for.

```
    @classmethod
    def _match_slug(cls, slug):
        """ Method that checks if we still have a match in the db for current 'slug' """
        return cls.objects.filter(slug=slug).count()
```

I have 10 models in my application and each has this `_match_slug` method. I want to take this method to the parent class, so when I call `self._match_slug(slug_to_check)` it calls the method with its appropriate class `cls`.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think what you are referring to is Polymorphism. I thinkt the method should work as is if it is defined int he parent class. Are you getting any errors when attempting to use it?

Comment: You probably want to make a Mixin and use it as base class for you 10 models.

Comment: I havn't tried it, and I was confused about what it was and how to use that, I had a concept in my mind. Can somone write a demo code for python?

Comment: You already have it! Move that method to a class, and make sure all of your models extend it, like this `class MyModel(Parent):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the method to your parent class:

```
class Parent(object):

    @classmethod
    def _match_slug(cls, slug):
        """ Method that checks if we still have a match in the db for current 'slug' """
        return cls.objects.filter(slug=slug).count()

class Child(Parent):
    ...

c = Child()
# Equivalent to Parent._match_slug(c.__class__, x)
c._match_slug(x)
```